Flutter Webrtc - Sending MediaStream between Isolates
Is it possible to send MediaStream between isolates?
Since only primitive types can be directly transferred between isolates, I've implemented the following extensions to handle this:

MediaStream Extension:
extension MediaStreamExtension on MediaStream {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    final Map<String, dynamic> map = {
      "streamId": id,
      "ownerTag": ownerTag,
      "audioTracks": getAudioTracks()
          .map((final MediaStreamTrack track) => track.toMap())
          .toList(),
      "videoTracks": getVideoTracks()
          .map((final MediaStreamTrack track) => track.toMap())
          .toList(),
    };
    return map;
  }
}



MediaStreamTrack Extension:
extension MediaStreamTrackJson on MediaStreamTrack {
  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
        "id": id,
        "label": label,
        "kind": kind,
        "enabled": enabled,
      };
}




After converting the MediaStream to a map format, we send it to the main isolate.
In the main isolate, we attempt to convert the map back into a MediaStream to use with RTCVideoRenderer. The conversion is done as follows:
final MediaStream mediaStream = MediaStreamNative.fromMap(streamData);
final tracks = mediaStream.getTracks();
print(tracks);

log:
[Track(id: 8716d90b-4131-46d1-8846-32061d0fac62, kind: audio, label: audio, enabled: true, muted: false), Track(id: 03315f09-90d9-45dd-b39e-2b389ff6dcd0, kind: video, label: video, enabled: true, muted: false)]
We are able to obtain the MediaStream, but it only displays a black screen.
Will the above approach work?, or is there something specific we need to do to send the MediaStream between isolates?
